# CGContext, issue when drawing neighboring paths individually, don't blend together

Tags: swift, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgpath

this is my first post on stack, so pardon any etiquette problems I'm not aware of

I am creating a simple drawing engine for one of my apps. It is mostly based on Apple's Touch Canvas demo for the apple pencil
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/illustrating_the_force_altitude_and_azimuth_properties_of_touch_input

That engine works by stroking paths, since I need to vary the width smoothly I decided to do it by filling paths, the logic to create that path is very similar to this cocos2d project
https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/LineDrawing

I’m very happy with the performance of the engine at the moment, so I decided to be more ambitious: introduce variable opacity according to force. To do this, instead of drawing the whole path from the stroke, I subdivide it into segments, a segment looks like this using a stroke line

￼[image: strokedpath]

I draw each segment path one by one, in filled out form, it looks like this
[image: filledpath]

So no issues right? Well, if you have an Ipad (or zoom), you notice a problem

[image: stitchedpaths]
￼

The paths are actually stitched together! There is no smooth transition. Seems to be an antialiasing problem. What I noticed is that, if I very slightly offset the beginning of a new segment into the previous segment (right now, the end of the previous segment is the start of the new one), it seems to blend better , sometimes disappearing the stitches completely, but this is very tricky, while it works with colors at full opacity, when you reduce the opacity the same constant might not work, and sometimes there are variations in results when using the simulator vs a real device

I’m kinda lost here, is there any way kinda smooth the transition between segments?

This is my drawing routine, right now I'm using gradients, but I already tried to fill the path with a solid color with no clipping and got the same results

```
for (index,subpath) in pathResults.subPaths.enumerated(){
        //Si no es inicio de linea el primer segmento es historico para suavizar, no dibujar
        if !startOfLine && index == 0{
            continue
        }
        let colors = [properties.color.cgColor.copy(alpha: opacityForPoint(subpath.startPoint)),
                     properties.color.cgColor.copy(alpha: opacityForPoint(subpath.endPoint))]
            as CFArray
        if let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: context.colorSpace,
                                     colors: colors,
                                     locations: [0.0,1.0]){
            context.addPath(subpath.subpath)
            context.clip()
            context.drawLinearGradient(gradient,
                                       start: subpath.startPoint.properties.location,
                                       end: subpath.endPoint.properties.location,
                                       options: gradientOptions)
            context.resetClip()
        }
    }
```

this is the code for the context I draw in:

```
private lazy var frozenContext: CGContext = {
    let scale = self.properties.scale
    var size = self.properties.size

    size.width *= scale
    size.height *= scale
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                       width: Int(size.width),
                                       height: Int(size.height),
                                       bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                       bytesPerRow: 0,
                                       space: colorSpace,
                                       bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    context.concatenate(transform)

    return context
}()
```

Comment: This is really neat! One request though: make your images inline, so people don't have to click out to see them

Comment: There, sorry, had not enough reputation to attach them

Comment: I’m assuming you’re zooming by applying a transform to the view. If you didn’t do that, but instead transformed the coordinates yourself, you wouldn’t see those artifacts. Plus, it wouldn’t pixelate as you zoom in.

Comment: The view ("CanvasView") is in a scrollview at the moment, but on an ipad pro, even at 100% the stitches are somewhat noticeable. The context (frozenContext) is drawn to the CanvasView like in Apple's demo. If I redrew the whole thing every time I had to refresh the view it would take a (compounding) lifetime the longer the user draws